# self.removeFromSuperview() within UIView subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

**Context:**
I created a subclass of UIView (helloView) to display some text and a button on top of my MainViewController view.
This subclass is initialized in the MainVC `viewDidLoad` and added to the view: `view.addSubview(helloView)`

**Objective**: helloView has a UIButton (continueButton) with a target `dimissHelloView`. This method simply calls `self.removeFromSuperView()` in order to simply get ride of helloView on the screen.

**Problem**: a user interaction with the button breaks the code and returns a nil pointer exception (unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value). Despite a few hours on SO and Google searches, I couldn't find the right approach for dismissing a view via its own button subview.

**Previous troubleshooting**: It seems that superview is nil when the removeFromSuperview is called, but it is not if I use a breakpoint and call it out in the console.

**Code:** Ignore the attributes and constraints piece, the button creation and target action are at the bottom.

```
import UIKit

class HelloView: UIView {

    var helloText: String = ""
    var continueButton: UIButton!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        didLoad()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        didLoad()
    }

    func didLoad(){

        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        setContinueButton()
        self.addSubview(continueButton)
    }

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        setConstraints()
    }

    func setConstraints(){

        //remove any previous constraints
        for constraint in superview!.constraints {
            if constraint.firstItem as! UIView == self && constraint.secondItem as? UIView == superview {
                superview!.removeConstraint(constraint)
            }
        }

        // Hello View basic constraints
        let xAxisConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let yAxisConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        // check device orientation and add constraints consequently
        if UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation) {
            let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: -100)
            let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: -150)
            superview!.addConstraints([xAxisConstraint, yAxisConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
        }
        if UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation){
            let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: -100)
            let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: -300)
            superview!.addConstraints([xAxisConstraint, yAxisConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
        }

        // Continue Button constraints
        let centerXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: continueButton, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: continueButton, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -8)
        self.addConstraints([centerXConstraint, bottomConstraint])
    }

    func setContinueButton(){
        continueButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20))
        continueButton.setTitle("Continue", forState: .Normal)
        continueButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
        continueButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HelloView.dismissHelloView), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        continueButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    func dismissHelloView(){
        print(superview!)
        self.removeFromSuperview()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove a view from its superview, `didMoveToSuperview` is going to get called (the superview will be `nil`). Your `setConstraints` function is called from `didMoveToSuperview`, and it's force unwrapping `superview`, which is nil, causing the crash. The whole point of optionals is it forces you to consider what happens if something is nil.

Anyway, in your case you don't want anything to happen when the superview becomes nil, so I'd put something like this at the top of `didMoveToSuperview`:

```
guard superview != nil else { return }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @zpasternack, I didn't realize didMoveToSuperview was getting called on removeFromSuperview! Adding the guard statement for an early return solved the problem.